# SharePoint Rest API internal server error

Tags: sharepoint-addin, app, rest

When I deploy (or debug) the App and I call a REST service (retrieving list items)
I get always

> 500 Internal Server Error, Unknown Error

Maybe I tried to get the items before that the list has been created?
Do you have any ideas? How can I debug this problem?

Comment: You could perhaps check ULS. Also, are you querying host web app? And lastly, how does your request look like

Comment: If I refresh the page it works fine. My request is executed in a $.ajax call and looks like: myURL/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('MyLists')/items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mentioned that are using [jQuery.ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), you could print the error details using `error` handler as demonstrated below:

```
$.ajax({
        url: siteurl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listName + "')/items",
        method: "GET",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
        success: function (data) {
            //...
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
        }
});
```

or leverage the [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) tool to trace and diagnose REST requests.

[image]

Comment: Helped to debug the problem.(error in the list xml schema definition). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

go to the IIS logs and see if more information is given about
the 500 error code.
I have see this error when I want to work with REST and I see IIS log and know that Actually there was problem in behaviour configuration at sevice side and then the way  params I was passing at client end has problem.
So I hope this usefull!

Comment: how can I see the logs?

Comment: see this link for find IIS log https://portal.smartertools.com/kb/a2487/where-are-my-iis-log-files-stored.aspx